# UIWebView content sometimes not rendered

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

Briefly, my problem is: some PDFs loaded into some web views don't show up, while others do, as shown in the following pictures (please note that I edited the images placing fake pdf content, the original cannot be published).

Three PDFs loaded correctly into three UIWebViews
[image: Three PDFs loaded correctly into three UIWebViews]

Second UIWebView height is right and comes from the PDF height, but its content is not rendered
[image: Second UIWebView height is right and comes from the PDF height, but its content is not rendered]

My app has to show very short PDFs into a series of web views (assume that this is a mandatory requirement and that I cannot switch to anything else. The PDFs are LaTex generated and contain text which cannot be displayed into UILabel and so on. Also, they are about 4-5 rows length).

The layout is as following: there is a vertical scroll view which has a view (content view) as direct child. A single `UIWebView` (yellow background) is embedded inside a custom class that inherits from `UIView` (`PDFView`, blue background), so I can assign that class as the webview's delegate and perform the webview initialization+constraints settings in just one place. The webview `userInteraction` is disabled. Into the content view, I dynamically add one `PDFView` per PDF, setting up the constraints and calling `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` to load the PDF (which comes as `NSData` from a file on disk, the white frame). Since `PDFView` is the delegate of its `UIWebView`, when it finishes to load its content (the pdf), I change the webview height constraint to match the `webview.scrollview.contentsize.height`. This allows me to resize the webview so that it displays the entire PDF. Autolayout takes care of setting the scrollview `contentsize.height` so the user can scroll the entire list of pdf.

Everything seems to work fine but sometimes, on some webviews, the content is not rendered. When the call for `webViewDidFinishLoad:` triggers, the `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height` value is correct (in fact, the webview has the right height) and after autolayout finishes his work, the frame of the webview whose content has not been rendered has the correct dimensions. This leads me to think that it must be some sort of rendering problem, since it seems to happen randomly on different webviews and on different pdfs. Sometimes I have to manually push and pop the controller like 10 times before the problem arises, sometimes it appears just on the first push. Memory consumption seems to be fine and there aren't any memory warnings.

I checked every data and view: no one is nil. Also the delegate `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` is never invoked so the webview always succeeds in loading its content (`webViewDidFinishLoad:` is called every time, even for the webviews that don't display any content). The PDF data is fine since I loaded it into memory, saved again in another pdf file and opened with a PDF viewer. I'm not using storyboards but xibs. I'm targeting iOS 7+.

Code is as following:

**PDFView.h**

```
@interface PDFView : UIView

-(instancetype) initWithData:(NSData *)pdfData at:(NSInteger)position;

@end
```

**PDFView.m**

```
#import "PDFView.h"

@interface PDFView() <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView * contentUIWV;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint * contentHeightNSLC;

@end

@implementation PDFView

-(instancetype) initWithData:(NSData *)pdfData at:(NSInteger)position
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        [self initViews];
        [self setConstraints];
        [self fillViews:pdfData];

        self.tag = position;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) initViews
{
    _contentUIWV = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    [_contentUIWV setContentHuggingPriority:250 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
    _contentUIWV.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    _contentUIWV.delegate = self;
    _contentUIWV.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    _contentUIWV.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [self addSubview:_contentUIWV];
}

-(void) setConstraints
{
    _contentUIWV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;

    NSDictionary * viewsNSD = @{ @"contentUIWV":_contentUIWV };

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-8-[contentUIWV]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsNSD]];

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-8-[contentUIWV]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsNSD]];

    NSArray * constraintsNSA = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[contentUIWV(==1)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsNSD];

    self.contentHeightNSLC = constraintsNSA.firstObject;

    [self.contentUIWV addConstraints:constraintsNSA];
}

-(void) fillViews:(NSData *)pdfData
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"PDFView::fillViews: %ld %@", (long)self.tag, pdfData?@"NOT null":@"NULL");
    #endif

    [_contentUIWV loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
}

#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    return YES;
}

-(void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"PDFView::webView:didFailLoadWithError: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    #endif
}

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"PDFView::webViewDidFinishLoad: %ld new height (%ld)", (long)self.tag, (long)webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
    #endif
    self.contentHeightNSLC.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
}

@end
```

**Controller.m**

```
#import "Controller.h"
#import "PDFView.h"

@interface Controller ()

// This Mutable Array stores the NSData of each PDF (PDF are loaded form disk and stored as NSData)
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * exerciseDataNSMA;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainUIV;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollUISV;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentUIV;

@end

@implementation Controller

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ... omitted code inits self.exerciseDataNSMA and stores pdf content in it

    [self loadContentView];
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods

-(void) loadContentView
{
    // Subviews by name (used for constraint bindings)
    NSMutableDictionary * subviews = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // String in Visual Language Format to create vertical scrollview's contentview constraint
    NSMutableString *strVerticalConstraint = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"V:|"];

    for (NSInteger i=0; i<self.exerciseDataNSMA.count; i++)
    {
        PDFView * pdfView = [[PDFView alloc] initWithData:self.exerciseDataNSMA[i] at:i];
        pdfView.delegate = self;
        pdfView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self.contentUIV addSubview:pdfView];

        [self.contentUIV addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[pdfView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"pdfView":pdfView}]];

        NSString * exerciseUIVName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pdfView%ld", (long)i];

        [strVerticalConstraint appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]-8-", exerciseUIVName]];
        subviews[exerciseUIVName] = pdfView;
    }

    [strVerticalConstraint appendString:@"|"];

    // Add content view constraints
    [self.contentUIV addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:strVerticalConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:subviews]];
}

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{            
    // Without the cache disabled, the webviews do not resize their height
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"WebKitDiskImageCacheEnabled"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // ... unrelated stuff 

    return YES;
}
```

**Constraints** on Controller are as following:

[image: Constraints]

Note that the height constraint is removed at runtime.

Any idea why this happens? Any idea on how to solve it?

Here what I already tried:

1. Reproduced the problem on both iOS 7 and iOS8, on iPhone and on iPad. The number of webviews whose content is not rendered is greater on low specs devices (like iPhone 4s) than those with better resources (as the iPad 4);
2. Executing `loadContentView` without loading pdfData into the webview. After the controller has appeared, load the pdfData into the webviews;
3. Load the pdfdata sequentially, meaning that i do the same as B) and then I call `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` for the first webview, wait for `webViewDidFinishLoad:` and then repeat this sequence for the second webview and so on;
4. Force every webview to reload its content (since I don't have a way to detect a webview that doesn't render its content. This results in some webviews rendering their content again, some others not);
5. Use javascript to resize the webview (it didn't work at all);

Comment: i think it is not an issue.If you send multiple requests at a time, one with less content will gets loaded first. It also depends on network connectivity. What you probably need is to start loading each webview when one is finished.

Comment: Even if you put them on loop, it doesnt mean all requeests will be loaded sequentially

Comment: This is what I've done on point 3. Requests are not fired in loop: each is triggered after the previous one has finished loading its content, when webViewDidfinishLoad: is called. Also, the data isn't coming from network but from memory (which is loaded in the controller viewDidLoad, before the webviews are even instantiated)

Comment: you are calling initWithData in a loop. What does it mean ?

Comment: also I dont see any code that fires next request in webViewDidFinishLoad:

Comment: You are calling fillViews in a loop. What do you say about it?

Comment: Indeed, the code I posted shows how I have initially approached the problem (initWithData in a loop). In the last section of the post (Here what I already tried) I wrote which others ways I tried, e.g., in point 3, firing the loadData: in the sequential way you and I have descrived. I haven't post the code of every single experiment I have done, just a resume of them (otherwise it would take too much space). Firing the requests in a sequential way has already been done, resulting in the same problem.